# CPU capacity not fully used - Stuck at 16%

Tags: linux, hard-drive, windows-10, ssd, cpu

I just bought a new Laptop.
The problem is that it only uses 16% of its CPU capacity, and never goes over that. I have tried stressing the CPU, but even then it still doesn't go over 16%

Booting in linux, and doing the same, does stress it to 100%

Problem: Huge performance issues (eg chrome, explorer, basically everything) and FPS issues (ingame)

Context: Tempratures around 30-35 degrees on everyhing. 3 to 7 FPS ingame, medium to low graphics

**Things i tried:**

- High performance energy program, with Min and Max CPU usage to 100%
- Updating drives
- No settings were found in the BIOS
- No answers were found on any forum

**Specs**

- Windows 10
- Linux Ubuntu 16.04
- Intel Core I5-6200U CPU @ 2.30 GHz (4 CPU's)
- NVIDIA GeForce 940MX
- Intel Core HD Graphics 520
- SSD (128 GB), HDD (1 TB)
- Standard PEAQ PNB 2015-I5N1 (laptop)

[Linux performance image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBJum.jpg)

[Windows performance image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzneI.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I see it you have 3 options

1. Reinstall Windows using either the recovery media that the laptop came with or downloading standard windows burning it to a DVD/USB and installing it that way.
2. Ask for a replacement, since the laptop is new it should still have warranty. Take it back to the shop and get it replaced or talk to the manufacturer.
3. Use Linux on that computer and delete windows...

Comment: Ye, im gonna return it to the store then. I need windows for visual studio, so i need that.

Answer (score 0):

I actually come up with a solution. It seems that for one reason or another Windows thinks that the "normal" power state is the power state that's supposed to be lowest possible.

That is probably why truning on and off does not help, because there is no power state change in between.

**What actually helped was instead of restarting to use sleep.** That way the computer switched to the C3 sleep state and by waking up something got switched back to where it was supposed to be. The frequencies are back to 3.3GHz :)

Comment: Oops, accidentally posted the answer here instead of https://superuser.com/questions/1241844/cpu-is-stuck-at-its-minimal-frequency/1241848#1241848, but I'll leave it here because coincidentally it may answer this as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the exact same issue. Inspired by Tomáš Fejfar's answer, I disabled all C-states and Intel SpeedStep, fixing the problem instantly.

Just go to your BIOS Setup page (usually by pressing DEL or F12 while POSTing) and disable any power saving options.

And yes, I understand that some people like to use power saving modes, but I always stay clear of them. I'm just sharing my solution, even if it's not for everyone. :)